# Non local lambda and capturing variables - what does "block scope" means

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm currently playing with c++11 lambdas and found a example that I can't understand. According to the Standard:

> A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (3.3.3) is a local lambda expression; any
>   other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-list in its lambda-introducer

so, I created trivial example:

```
int a = 10;
auto x  = [a] { return 1;};
int main() {
    int k = 5;
    auto p = [k]{ return k; };
    return 0;
}
```

The code in ideone: http://ideone.com/t9emu5

I was expecting that this code will not compile because of capturing variable in non-block scope (or at least think that the auto x  = ... part is not in the block-scope). But the code is compiling - is it ok?

If is it ok - what the block scope is?

(I'm not sure what compiler version I use because currently I have access only to ideone site.

Thanks for explaining!

Comment: so, what scope is non-block scope?

Comment: @DanielFrey Huh? A block is a compound statement, and a namespace certainly is not a block. See [basic.scope.block]/1 and [stmt.block]

Comment: @DyP Sorry, I got confused. You are completely right!

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, I don't think so. The question is specific to lambda captures.

Comment: +1: Sounds like a possible GCC bug, especially since clang identifies another problem with the code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right, it's more about the compiler behaviour than about the language. It's fine as it is then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like this is a compiler extension. g++4.8.1 compiles this while giving a warning:

> warning: capture of variable ‘a’ with non-automatic storage duration [enabled by default]

clang++3.4 doesn't compile this:

> error: 'a' cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration

Both refer to [expr.prim.lambda]/10

> The identifiers in a capture-list are looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1); each such lookup shall find a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the local lambda expression.

It seems they don't additionally check the enclosing scope of the lambda, I can imagine it would be redundant (there are no names of variables with automatic storage duration at non-block/namespace scope).

---

A block scope is defined in [basic.scope.block]/1

> A name declared in a block (6.3) is local to that block; it has block scope.

And a block is defined as:

> So that several statements can be used where one is expected, the compound statement (also, and equivalently, called “block”) is provided.
>
> *compound-statement:*
>            `{` *statement-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `}`

So you're right that your globally declared lambda is *not* in a block scope.

Comment: To add: You can have GCC reject it by using the compilation flag `-pedantic-errors` (in addition to `-std=c++11`), which I recommend (and `-Wall -Wextra` too). Ideone doesn't let you specify compiler options, but e.g. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) does ([GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) too, but it only compiles (and shows assembly output), it doesn't link and run). (See e.g. http://isocpp.org/get-started for more online C++ compilers.)

Comment: @gx_ That seems to be wrong. I compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and was never told about this error in my code (which probably resulted from moving the lambda out of a local scope), across `g++` version 5 and now 6.1. Adding `-pedantic-errors`, rather unsurprisingly, does nothing to change this. `g++` just doesn't warn me. I guess I need to ask `clang++` for a 2nd opinion more often... sigh